# Additional arguments for custom DBAL drivers

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, dbal

I want to create a custom DBAL driver which I will be using with the "driverClass" argument in the DBAL configuration. This works, but my driver needs additional classes to work. For instance, it needs a caching client and an HTTP client (it basically will fetch credentials remotely).

The issue is that inside DBAL's driver manager, a custom driver class is instantiated without arguments, so I cannot use a constructor to add additional services. I could create setters so I can use setter-injection, but I think this will cause problems when using the driver in Symfony applications for instance.

All the custom DBAL drivers I've researched are using tight coupling with HTTP clients and other services but I don't want this (I don't want to force users APCu caching for instance).

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Never tried it myself.  Have you considered using a custom wrapper class?  That at least accepts a $params argument in the constructor.  Not sure how to get your services into $params but if you can then you could pass them onto the driver.  Kind of a shame the DriverManager does not allow you to pass it an actual driver instance.

Comment: I could add an $option to the connection params that has the needed dependencies. I'm just not sure how if this would work correctly with Doctrine/Symfony. I'm